# Codechef is rejecting my solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am newbie on codechef and i was trying to solve the following question however my code runs fine on my machine, i also tested it with some cases.

Question is as follows :-

In Byteland it is always the military officer's main worry to order his soldiers on parade correctly. Luckily, ordering soldiers is not really such a problem. If a platoon consists of n men, all of them have different rank (from 1 - lowest to n - highest) and on parade they should be lined up from left to right in increasing order of rank.

Sounds simple, doesn't it? Well, Sgt Johnny thought the same, until one day he was faced with a new command. He soon discovered that his elite commandos preferred to do the fighting, and leave the thinking to their superiors. So, when at the first rollcall the soldiers lined up in fairly random order it was not because of their lack of discipline, but simply because they couldn't work out how to form a line in correct order of ranks. Sgt Johnny was not at all amused, particularly as he soon found that none of the soldiers even remembered his own rank. Over the years of service every soldier had only learned which of the other soldiers were his superiors. But Sgt Johnny was not a man to give up easily when faced with a true military challenge. After a moment's thought a solution of brilliant simplicity struck him and he issued the following order: "men, starting from the left, one by one, do: (step forward; go left until there is no superior to the left of you; get back in line).". This did indeed get the men sorted in a few minutes. The problem was solved... for the time being.

The next day, the soldiers came in exactly the same order as the day before, and had to be rearranged using the same method. History repeated. After some weeks, Sgt Johnny managed to force each of his soldiers to remember how many men he passed when going left, and thus make the sorting process even faster.

If you know how many positions each man has to walk to the left, can you try to find out what order of ranks the soldiers initially line up in?

Input

The first line of input contains an integer t<=50, the number of test cases. It is followed by t test cases, each consisting of 2 lines. The first line contains a single integer n (1<=n<=200000). The second line contains n space separated integers wi, denoting how far the i-th soldier in line must walk to the left when applying Sgt Johnny's algorithm.

Output

For each test case, output a single line consisting of n space separated integers - the ranks of the soldiers, given from left to right in their initial arrangement.

Example

Input:
2
3
0 1 0
5
0 1 2 0 1

Output:
2 1 3
3 2 1 5 4
Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
 int t,n;
 cin >> t;

  while(t>0){

    cin >> n;
    int array[n+1];
    int stepsmoved,i;

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }


    for(i = 1; i <=n; i++){
        cin >> stepsmoved;
        if(stepsmoved == 0){}
        else{
            int x;
            x = array[i];
            for (int j = i; j> i- stepsmoved; j--){
                array[j] = array[j-1];
            }
            array[i-stepsmoved] = x;
        }

    }

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
  cout<<endl;
  t--;
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

So is there something logically or syntactically wrong?

Comment: You don't know if there is something syntactically wrong or not?

Comment: No, according to the compiler there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Did you find something wrong?

Comment: You have a logical problem. You assume that the first soldier in resulting line did his move in a last turn. This is not really necessarily.

Comment: *Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages* -- So why did you use `int array[n+1];`?  First, it isn't valid C++ syntax, since you can't declare arrays using a variable as the number of items, and second, if `n` is large, you'll blow out the stack.  Just use `std::vector<int>`.  Also, why not hard-code the data that is failing into the program source instead of us having to look at `cin>>` statements?

Comment: @Serge yes you are right , thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the help, I'll definitely consider this.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena it would be interesting to see your solution when you find one ;)

Comment: @Serge thanks for replying, if you see that the last soldier moves first because the total number of his moves represents the total number of soldier who were ranked below him and stood on the right of him (initially), similarly for the second last soldier, and so on. Hence even if the last soldier moved first it doesn't matter because number of total movements influence the final outcome and not the sequence of movements.

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena -- To be honest, your post is not the first one submitted to "online judge" that suffers from exactly the same issues I pointed out -- it seems to be an epidemic to use stuff like variable length arrays (which are not standard) -- what winds up happening is either out-of-bounds accesses, excessive stack usage, or a combination of the two.  If the usage of VLA's were replaced with `std::vector`, plus using a few `vector::at()` statements thrown in to ensure that there are no out-of-bound accesses occurring, it would solve a lot, if not most of the errors that occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of 'unwinding' the sorting is relevant. 
Here is the code that demonstrates the statement above (the ranks are 1-based, the `1` - is highest, `10` - is lowest, array indices are 0-based):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dump(int *a) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
      printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int array[10] = {0}, steps[10] = {0};
    int i,j;
    srand(0);

    // Assign ranks in random order
    for (i = 0; i < 10;) {
        j = rand() % 10;
        if (!array[j])
        array[j] = ++i;
    }

    dump(array);

    // Sort according to the Sgt Johnny's initial idea
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; array[j] < array[i]; j++);
        if (j < i) {
            int k, temp = array[i];
            for (k = i; k > j; k--) {
                array[k] = array[k-1];
                steps[temp-1]++;
            }
            array[j] = temp;
            dump(array);
        }
    }
    printf("Steps:\n");
    dump(steps);
    printf("\n");

    // reconstruct the origina order
#if 1
    for (i = 10-1; i >= 0; i--)
#else
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
#endif
    {
        int s = steps[array[i]-1];
        for (j = i; s; s--, j++) {
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = temp;
        }
        dump(array);
    }
}
```

If the reconstruction is done in reverse order, then we get a sequence that matches original:

```
8 7 5 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
7 8 5 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
5 7 8 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
1 5 7 8 10 4 2 3 9 6 
1 4 5 7 8 10 2 3 9 6 
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 3 9 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 9 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Steps:
3 5 5 4 2 4 1 0 1 0 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 10 9 
1 2 3 4 5 8 7 10 9 6 
1 2 3 4 8 7 5 10 9 6 
1 2 3 8 7 5 10 4 9 6 
1 2 8 7 5 10 4 3 9 6 
1 8 7 5 10 4 2 3 9 6 
8 7 5 1 10 4 2 3 9 6
```

Otherwise, the reconstructed order does not match the original:

```
8 7 5 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
7 8 5 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
5 7 8 1 10 4 2 3 9 6 
1 5 7 8 10 4 2 3 9 6 
1 4 5 7 8 10 2 3 9 6 
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 3 9 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 9 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
Steps:
3 5 5 4 2 4 1 0 1 0 

2 3 4 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 4 1 5 6 7 3 8 9 10 
2 4 5 6 7 1 3 8 9 10 
2 4 5 7 1 3 8 6 9 10 
2 4 5 7 3 8 6 1 9 10 
2 4 5 7 3 8 6 1 9 10 
2 4 5 7 3 8 1 9 10 0 
2 4 5 7 3 8 1 10 9 0 
2 4 5 7 3 8 1 10 0 9 
2 4 5 7 3 8 1 10 0 6
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to help me understand the problem,  but according to my understanding of the problem steps represent the actual steps moved by the soldier, this implies that first soldier (soldier 1) would not walk at all because he would not have any soldier to his left who is ranked lower than him, hence every soldier in the final arrangement (i.e. according to the sequence 1,2,3...) cannot walk more steps than his current position -1(a soldier at x can only walk upto x-1 steps ).

Comment: quoting the problem " The second line contains n space separated integers wi, denoting how far the i-th soldier in line must walk to the left when applying Sgt Johnny's algorithm. "

Comment: What keep you from reading all numbers in that second line into array and then process that array in reverse order?

Comment: Yes, the soldier that stand at the very left of the original line would always have to step zero steps. But who said that his position would be the leftmost one in the sorted line as well?

Comment: No, the first soldier in the sorted line won't walk any steps to the left because he has no one ranked lower than him. hence he will look left and would never step ahead to walk

Comment: The first soldier in unsorted line!

Comment: Oh yes!! i was doing it in the wrong arrangement and hence it was wrong!! Thanks a ton!!!